# Absolute path in dotnet watch run command doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

To run dotnet core application with specified absolute path we need to run following command:

```
dotnet run -p C:\foo\bar\Project\Project.csproj
```

But it seems it doesn't work the same with `dotnet watch run`:

```
watch : Could not find a MSBuild project file in 'C:\directory\where\we\execute\command'. Specify which project to use with the --project option.
```

Running the same command with `-project` instead of `-p` doesn't help however...

> Dotnet watch help specifies `-p` or `-project` parameter anyway:
>
> Microsoft DotNet File Watcher 2.1.1-rtm-30846
>
> Usage: dotnet watch [options] [[--] ...]
>
> Options:   -?|-h|--help            Show help information
>   -p|--project   The project to watch   -q|--quiet              Suppresses all output except warnings and errors   -v|--verbose
>   Show verbose output   --list                  Lists all discovered
>   files without starting the watcher   --version               Show
>   version information
>
> Environment variables:
>
> DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER   When set to '1' or 'true',
>   dotnet-watch will poll the file system for   changes. This is required
>   for some file systems, such as network shares,   Docker mounted
>   volumes, and other virtual file systems.
>
> DOTNET_WATCH   dotnet-watch sets this variable to '1' on all child
>   processes launched.
>
> Remarks:   The special option '--' is used to delimit the end of the
>   options and   the beginning of arguments that will be passed to the
>   child dotnet process.   Its use is optional. When the special option
>   '--' is not used,   dotnet-watch will use the first unrecognized
>   argument as the beginning   of all arguments passed into the child
>   dotnet process.
>
> For example: dotnet watch -- --verbose run
>
> Even though '--verbose' is an option dotnet-watch supports, the use
>   of '--'   indicates that '--verbose' should be treated instead as an
>   argument for   dotnet-run.
>
> Examples:   dotnet watch run   dotnet watch test

What's wrong then? Why absolute path to project doesn't work with `dotnet watch run` while works with `dotnet run`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to specify the
`--project` option on the `watch` command rather than on the `run` command:

```
dotnet watch --project C:\foo\bar\Project\Project.csproj run
```

There's a note in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch#run-net-core-cli-commands-using-dotnet-watch) that covers this:

> You can use `dotnet watch --project <PROJECT>` to specify a project to watch. For example, running `dotnet watch --project WebApp run` from the root of the sample app will also run and watch the *WebApp* project.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure, but dotnet watch is looking for file changes in the current directory. So if you use absolute path it must know where should it looks for changes. Of course, such implementation is possible but I just think that nobody thinked about it when implementing `watch` command

Comment: Good point. I think it's a bug however because docs clearly describe we can specify a path to a project which we want to watch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, its just a minor error, you have to enter in the project directory before executing dotnet command, like:

> cd yourAppName
> dotnet watch run
> It'll run